# How do I write a query to filter out distinct values in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a question about filtering out SQL tables.

I have a website where users can sign up and each sign up will generate a unique customer ID.

I am running a test where a user will be put into different types of segments (new visitor, returning visitor, existing customer). The experience will be personalized for each user segment.

Now I want to analyze the results. I can get the segment info for each user and their respective customer segment. The thing though is the user can change into user segments dynamically, for example, you can be a new visitor one day and signed up, then become existing customer another day.

The thing is I want to know how many incremental sign ups I get from existing customers. 
I can create a table of new user segment company IDs and returning users segment company IDs. Now I want to create a table of existing customers where their company IDs are **not from** both new user and returning visitors. What type of join condition should I use in this case?

Here are the table examples:

New Visitor Table

```
Segment name                 | Company ID
-----------------------------+------------
New Visitor- Control         | abcde     
New Visitor- Variation       | ffgg12
```

Returning Visitor Table

```
Segment name                       | Company ID
-----------------------------------+------------
Returning Visitor- Control         | Gg121     
Returning Visitor- Variation       | cc4234
```

I want to create a table where company ID is not IN both of above tables.

Many thanks in advance.

--Edit-- Here is the query I am trying to create:

WITH segment_info AS (SELECT date, segment_id, visitor_id FROM main_table WHERE (segment_id LIKE 'new_visitor' OR segment_id LIKE 'returning_visitor' OR segment_id LIKE 'existing_customer') AND date >= '2018-06-01'),
                                                                                                                newvisitor AS (SELECT DISTINCT visitor_id, segment_id, date) FROM main_table WHERE segment_id = 'new_visitor'),

returnvisitor AS (SELECT DISTINCT visitor_id, segment_id, date) FROM main_table WHERE segment_id = 'returning_visitor'),

existing_customer AS (SELECT DISTINCT visitor_id, segment_id, date) FROM main_table WHERE segment_id = 'existing_customer' AND visitor_id NOT IN (SELECT visitor_id FROM newvisitor UNION ALL SELECT visitor_id FROM returnvisitor))

--
The problem is the number of New Visitors + Returning Visitors + Existing Customers do not match against the total number of all Visitors.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. Also show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to create a table where company ID is not IN both of above
>   tables.

Use UNION ALL operator if you want filter out companies that are are in one of these tables (or in both tables):

```
SELECT * FROM some_table
WHERE ID Not In (
  SELECT Company_ID FROM New_Visitor_Table
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Company_ID FROM Returning_Visitor_Table
)
```

Use JOIN if you want to filter out companies that are in both tables at the same time:

```
SELECT * FROM some_table
WHERE ID Not In (
  SELECT Company_ID 
  FROM New_Visitor_Table
  JOIN Returning_Visitor_Table
  USING ( Company_ID  )
)
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I am thinking right now. Let me try it out

Comment: Hello, I am trying to write a query like below but the numbers don't add up. Total Unique count of visitors ID does not equal to total unique count of new visitors, total unique count of returning visitors and total unique count of returning visitors. Here is my query:

Comment: I have added the query in main question

Answer (score 0):

It was really hard to get what you wanted to implement. That's why there are two different solutions.

#### Based on what you originally wrote and your example tables

Providing you have two different tables with customers identified by company IDs, when you need to create a table for those customers which **are not** from your two tables, your query would like something like this:

```
select
    date,
    segment_id,
    visitor_id
from
    main_table t
where
    lower(t.segment_id) like ('%existing_customer%')
    and t.date >= '2018-06-01'
    and not exists (
        select null 
        from new_visitor_table
        where visitor_id = t.visitor_id
        union all
        select null 
        from returning_visitor_table
        where visitor_id = t.visitor_id
    );
```

Or, if you work only with main table without separating your visits:

```
select
    date,
    segment_id,
    visitor_id
from
    main_table t
where
    lower(t.segment_id) like ('%existing_customer%')
    and t.date >= '2018-06-01'
    and not exists (
        select null 
        from main_table
        where lower(segment_id) not like '%new_visitor%'
            and lower(segment_id) not like '%returning_visitor%'
            and visitor_id = t.visitor_id
    );
```

#### Based on my try to understand of your query

I think the correct one would look something like this:

```
select
    date,
    segment_id,
    visitor_id
from
    main_table t
where
    t.segment_id = 'existing_customer'
    and t.date >= '2018-06-01'
    and not exists (
        select null 
        from main_table
        where segment_id in ('new_visitor', 'returning_visitor')
            and visitor_id = t.visitor_id
    );
```

So, I'm not sure which is suitable for you, but hope one of them will lead you to your original goal.

Comment: Thank you I will try this out. The difficulty / issue here is that same visitor ID can be present across all three segments at the same time (because it is a web based customer segment - so when I visit the site first time, then returns, then converts)